# Create Swap Chain Failed

Tags: c++, directx

I am following a DX sample & MSDN reference, but I hit a wall now.

I get the HRESULT of E_InvalidArg from D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain().
I know it is the IDXGIAdapter I passed, since it works if I change it to null.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my initialization. Maybe someone with better knowledge knows what I did wrong. Here it is:

The vars:

```
vector<IDXGIAdapter1*> vAdapters;
IDXGIAdapter1* selectedVAdapter; // Constructor inits this to null
```

Methods:

```
void refreshVideoAdapters(){
    IDXGIAdapter1* pAdapter;
    IDXGIFactory1* pFactory=NULL;

    uint lastID=0;
    if(selectedVAdapter){
        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1* desc=NULL;
        selectedVAdapter->GetDesc1(desc);
        lastID=desc->DeviceId;
        releaseVideoAdapter();
    }

    if(FAILED(CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)&pFactory))) return;

    for(uint i=0; pFactory->EnumAdapters1(i, &pAdapter)!=DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND; i++){
        vAdapters.push_back(pAdapter);

        if(lastID){
            DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1* desc=NULL;
            pAdapter->GetDesc1(desc);
            if(lastID==desc->DeviceId){
                selectedVAdapter=pAdapter;
                lastID=0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(pFactory) pFactory->Release();
}
void releaseVideoAdapter(){
    for(uint i=0; i<vAdapters.size(); i++){
        vAdapters[i]->Release();
        vAdapters[i]=NULL;
    }
    vAdapters.clear();
    selectedVAdapter=NULL;
}
IDXGIAdapter1* getVideoAdapter(){return selectedVAdapter;}
bool setVideoAdapter(uint num=0){
    if(num<vAdapters.size()){
        selectedVAdapter=vAdapters[num];
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Relevant part of the call:

```
       ...
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[]={
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    };
    uint featuresSize=ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[]={
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    uint driversSize=ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    refreshVideoAdapters();
    setVideoAdapter();

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = 42;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = 42;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    HRESULT success=D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        selectedVAdapter, driver, NULL, flag, featureLevels, featuresSize, 
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &swapChain, &deviceInterface,
        &selectedFeatureLevel, &deviceContext);

       ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show the entire D3D11CXreateDeviceAndSwapChain() call, so I can just guess -- did you heed that paragraph from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> If you set the pAdapter parameter to a non-NULL value, you must also set the DriverType
>   parameter to the D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN value. If you set the pAdapter parameter to a
>   non-NULL value and the DriverType parameter to the D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE value,
>    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain returns an HRESULT of E_INVALIDARG.

Easy to get trapped by that one, since "hey, I want the device to use hardware support" :-)

Comment: Ohh. I didnt see that note. Thats what killed me. :D If I understand correctly, IDXGIAdapter represents a video card, right? Why is the driver not suppose to be set to hardware if a video card manually selected?

Comment: There's probably a reason for that, but I'm still struggling with all the rest, so I never really cared about the "why-s" behind the "do-s" :-) In fact, a "do" is always a good thing, considering it means one less choice I have to figure out :-)