# Create Swap Chain Failed 2.0

Tags: c++, directx

I had a problem with my D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(). I thought I got a solution in a prev thread, so I already marked it as solved. [[Create Swap Chain Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618933/create-swap-chain-failed])

Looks like I fooled myself when I accidentally returned the HRESULT as a bool...

I been fighting this problem all day & still have not figured it out. Here are bunch of debug info about the inputs & outputs...

**1] Taking the advice to use UNKNOWN with a non-null vAdapter:**
[Debug Pic http://content.wuala.com/contents/RandomClown/Public/RandomCrap/Debug%201.png](http://content.wuala.com/contents/RandomClown/Public/RandomCrap/Debug%201.png)

**2] Following the DX sample by leaving it null & using type HARDWARE:**
[Debug Pic http://content.wuala.com/contents/RandomClown/Public/RandomCrap/Debug%202.png](http://content.wuala.com/contents/RandomClown/Public/RandomCrap/Debug%202.png)

The pics might be enough for someone to spot out the problem, but in case it was something else, code:

```
//      This is some relevant stuff [anything referenced] in the class.

Graphics(){
    selectedVAdapter=NULL;
    deviceInterface=NULL;
    deviceContext=NULL;
    swapChain=NULL;
}

bool initDevice(HWND &hWnd){
    HRESULT success=S_OK;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[]={
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    };
    uint featuresSize=ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels);

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[]={
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, // Needed for manual vid adapter setting
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    uint driversSize=ARRAYSIZE(driverTypes);

    refreshVideoAdapters();
    setVideoAdapter();

    //setSampleQuality();

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory(&sd, sizeof(sd));
    sd.BufferCount = settings.bufferCount;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = settings.width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = settings.height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = settings.colorDepth;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = settings.rateNumerator;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = settings.rateDenominator;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = settings.sampleCount;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = settings.sampleQuality;
    sd.Windowed = !settings.fullScreen;

    uint flag=0;
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        flag|=D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    #endif

    for(uint i=0; i<driversSize; i++){ // SwapChain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driver=driverTypes[i];
        success=D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
            //NULL,
            selectedVAdapter, driver, NULL, flag,
            featureLevels, featuresSize, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd,
            &swapChain, &deviceInterface, &selectedFeatureLevel, &deviceContext);
        if(SUCCEEDED(success)) break;
    }

    return SUCCEEDED(success);
}

//      Methods to manage video adapters
void refreshVideoAdapters(){
    IDXGIAdapter1* pAdapter;
    IDXGIFactory1* pFactory=NULL;

    uint lastID=0;
    if(selectedVAdapter){
        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1* desc=NULL;
        selectedVAdapter->GetDesc1(desc);
        lastID=desc->DeviceId;
        releaseVideoAdapters();
    }

    if(FAILED(CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)&pFactory))) return;

    for(uint i=0; pFactory->EnumAdapters1(i, &pAdapter)!=DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND; i++){
        vAdapters.push_back(pAdapter);

        if(lastID){
            DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1* desc=NULL;
            pAdapter->GetDesc1(desc);
            if(lastID==desc->DeviceId){
                selectedVAdapter=pAdapter;
                lastID=0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(pFactory) pFactory->Release();
}
void releaseVideoAdapters(){
    for(uint i=0; i<vAdapters.size(); i++){
        vAdapters[i]->Release();
        vAdapters[i]=NULL;
    }
    vAdapters.clear();
    selectedVAdapter=NULL;
}
IDXGIAdapter1* getVideoAdapter(){return selectedVAdapter;}
bool setVideoAdapter(uint num=0){
    if(num<vAdapters.size()){
        selectedVAdapter=vAdapters[num];
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Member vars
private:
SettingsGraphicsDevice settings;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL selectedFeatureLevel;

vector<IDXGIAdapter1*> vAdapters;
IDXGIAdapter1* selectedVAdapter;

ID3D11Device* deviceInterface;
ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext;
IDXGISwapChain* swapChain;
```

Settings struct from that code:

```
struct SettingsGraphicsDevice{
    uint width, height;
    bool fullScreen, vsync;
    uint rateNumerator;
    uint rateDenominator;
    uint bufferCount;
    uint sampleCount, sampleQuality;
    DXGI_FORMAT colorDepth;
    float minDist, maxDist;

    SettingsGraphicsDevice(){
        width=height=0;
        fullScreen=0;
        vsync=0;

        rateNumerator=0;
        rateDenominator=1;
        bufferCount=1;
        sampleCount=1, sampleQuality=0;
        colorDepth=DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT;

        minDist=0.1f;
        maxDist=1000.0f;
    }

};
```

Thanks for reading. Hope a solution is found this time.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You are ignoring another piece of advice given somewhere in the MSDN: when you use fullscreen, you should created a windowed swapchain and set it to fullscreen afterwards. Either way, since you're not doing fullscreen: did you try leaving the refresh rate values at 0? Also, a quick peek at my code shows that I use DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, although I currently have no clue whether that's the correct mode. Work in progress :-)

Comment: Yeah, I am in windowed mode, & my refresh rate is on 0.  I will try out that color mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and Paste from my comment: "Also, a quick peek at my code shows that I use DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, although I currently have no clue whether that's the correct mode.". Ok, so it's in an answer now :-)

Yeah, the formats... the DXGI_FORMAT is a rather large enumeration, but in many situations only certain formats are allowed. It shouldn't be too surprising that only certain formats are allowed for displaying, whether it's fullscreen or not.

I got the value that I used from the docs (as usual), specifically the list in the [DXGI_MODE_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description. I don't actually know whether I'm creating a blt-block transfer swapchain, but decided that these values are as good as any to start with, and even though I don't care about feature level 9 it seemed pretty safe :-)

I have no idea why your code seemed to work wit a null-adapter; I think that's confusing. Maybe the debug runtime would have caught it?

Comment: The samples show it initializes with a NULL adapter. I think it defaults to the 1st adapter. Also, would it be correct to say "adapter = video card"?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to that color mode [DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM] worked. I get S_OK now. Why do the other color modes exist if they dont work?

Comment: DXGI formats depends on resource (texture/buffer) usage, so not all of them are allowed depending on what you want to do with them, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476498(v=vs.85).aspx for format supports